# Detected fraudulent charges to my account but I cannot close the card until another payment goes through

Tags: fraud, debit-card

Today I detected two charges to my card, both on the same day.  I called my bank (chase) but the only solution offered was to block and close the card.  However, I am currently doing some processes with USCIS and until they charge the fee attached to my paperwork I cannot close the card since then that process would just fail.

If the process fails, my process would be rejected and it seems I cannot resubmit the process per https://www.uscis.gov/forms/pay-a-credit-card:

> You may use Visa, MasterCard, American Express, and Discover. Make sure the card has enough money to cover the fee. We will reject your application, petition, or request if the card is declined, and we will not attempt to process your credit card payment a second time.

This is a special circumstance where a payment must go through on the potentially compromised card.

Does anyone know any other option to ensure that that payment goes through but also preventing further charges in a card that might have been compromised? Are charges like that usually because of a compromised card? Or some kind of sweep/random scam?

Comment: Can't you contact USCIS (whoever that is) and provide them with a new credit card number?

Comment: @chepner It's US Citizenship and Immigration Services. In other words, an agency that may hold OP's life in its hands. Presumably that's why he's being so careful and doesn't want to do anything that could complicate his case with them.

Comment: On the other hand, USCIS is used to stuff like this happening and it's very unlikely that they wouldn't be able to handle it. Get a new card, then call them up and give them the new details, then close the old card.

Comment: How long do you expect to have to wait for USCIS to complete the charges? The longer a potentially compromised card is active, the longer the crooks can use it.

Comment: Also regarding why this is a special case, "You may use a MasterCard, Visa, American Express, and Discover card. Make sure that there is enough money on the credit card to process the entire fee. If your credit card is declined, then your petition will also be rejected. If this happens, then USCIS will not be processing your petition for a second time." per https://www.stilt.com/blog/2019/08/g-1450/

Comment: Also "You may use Visa, MasterCard, American Express, and Discover. Make sure the card has enough money to cover the fee. We will reject your application, petition, or request if the card is declined, and we will not attempt to process your credit card payment a second time." from https://www.uscis.gov/forms/pay-a-credit-card

Comment: Did you mention these special charges to Chase when you talked to them?  They may have a system for dealing with cases like this where you have initiated a charge but it hasn't gone through yet.

Comment: @Dragonel Yea, the issue is that the carge isn't really 'pending'.  You send a form with the info for the card to USCIS and it won't be pending until they actually process that and place the charge.  (Really not a good system overall but I suppose they can afford to be like that).

Comment: Chase might still be able to selectively allow a charge from USCIS, but deny charges from any other source. (I'm not sure I would trust Chase to get this right, though. Worse, given that Chase is already aware of fraudulent charges on the card, I would be concerned about them "helpfully" denying a legitimate charge from USCIS when it does come through.)

Comment: "If the process fails, my process would be rejected and it seems I cannot resubmit the process ". I don't think a rejection on these grounds prevents you from starting a new application; it just halts further reconsideration of the rejected one (even for a simple fix like changing payment options). The Rejection Notices section also mentions filing a corrected application; you may be able to do this, paying by some other method rather than by credit card this time.

Comment: Failure to cancel the credit card in a timely manner may have bad consequences on your ability to claim the funds back. And of couse involve you in additional charges up to the credit card's maximum balance (plafond, credit line, whatever you call)

Comment: Chase definitely has the ability to close the card for all usage except by a single merchant.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, but I also agree with chepner that I wouldn't trust them to get this right, especially without the merchant making the initial charge for them to key off of (like with a virtual credit card where that first merchant to use it locks it in). But I would hope that with some manual effort they could find another charge on someone else's card and key off of that.

Comment: OP: So what happened? Did you manage to keep USCIS happy?

Answer (score 1):

Long, long, long ago my parents hit a situation where there was outstanding legitimate charges on a compromised card.  The credit card company was able to reissue the card while allowing the legitimate charges through.

I have had no occasion to do something like this since then but I would certainly ask the credit card company if something of the sort could be done.

Answer (score -2):

I know that if the charges that you want to go through is pending you don't need to worry about it going through. The charge will go through anyway even if the card is canceled. If you are worried, you should call your bank and make sure but I really recommend closing the card if you know there are fraudulent charges. There may be more so I don't think you should wait